# How to add information to a mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I want to add some information to a mind map. I am trying to follow a sample example [here](https://github.com/walmes/Tikz) but whenever I try to add through this command

```
(\node at (88.000:27em) [anchor = west] {next: this is next test};)
```

it gives me that information in the same circular node as used for others. What I want to do is to add either a legend (No symbols required) type square where I can add information about some abbreviations (more desireable)
or just annotate the node.[image: desired display of information]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, mindmap, grow cyclic, text width=2.5cm, minimum size=1cm, align=flush center, every node/.style=concept, concept color=violet=!30,
        level 1/.append style={level distance=3.5cm,sibling angle=135},
        level 2/.append style={level distance=3.0cm,sibling angle=60},
        level 3/.append style={level distance=2.5cm,sibling angle=50},
        level 4/.append style={level distance=2.0cm,sibling angle=60},
        ]
        \node  [left color=violet!40, middle color=red!10, right color=white!30]{\textbf{Checking}}
            child [minimum size=0.5pt, concept color=violet!50] { node [text width=2.0cm] {State}
        child [minimum size=0.1pt,concept color=violet!30] { node [text width=1.5cm] {F}
            child [minimum size=0.1pt,concept color=violet!30] {node [text width=1.5cm]  {T}}
            }
        child [minimum size=0.1pt, concept color=violet!30] { node  {A123}
        child [minimum size=0.1pt, concept color=violet!30] { node [text width=1.5cm] {12}}
        child [minimum size=0.1pt, concept color=violet!30] { node [text width=1.5cm] {random}}
              }
              }
              child [minimum size=0.5pt, concept color=violet!50] { node [text width=2.0cm] {Mix}
            child [minimum size=0.1pt, concept color=violet!30] { node [text width=1.5cm]  {QR}}
            child [minimum size=0.1pt, concept color=violet!30] { node [text width=1.5cm] {ST}}
            }
            child [minimum size=0.5pt,concept color=violet!50] { node [text width=2.0cm] {Next}
            child [minimum size=0.1pt,concept color=violet!30] { node [text width=1.5cm] {some data}
            child [minimum size=0.1pt,concept color=violet!30] {node [text width=1.5cm]  {new}}
            child[minimum size=0.1pt,concept color=violet!30]{node[text width=1.5cm]  {old}
            }
            }
            child [minimum size=0.1pt,concept color=violet!30] { node [text width=1.5cm] {M}
             child [minimum size=0.1pt,concept color=violet!30] {node [text width=1.5cm]  {MS}
             child [minimum size=0.1pt,concept color=violet!30] {node [text width=1.5cm]  {X}}
             }
              }
            child [minimum size=0.1pt,concept color=violet!30] { node [text width=1.5cm] {HAS}
             child [minimum size=0.1pt,concept color=violet!30] {node [text width=1.5cm]  {HAVE}}
            } 
            };

    \end{tikzpicture}
         \caption{Testing.} \label{mindmap}
        \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome. Please provide a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and more importantly show explicitly what you have tried inside the code.

Comment: I have modified it as you have suggested. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no detailed information on what you want to achieve, but this is just to tell you that it is straightforward to label nodes from "outside".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,mindmap,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[baseline, mindmap, grow cyclic, minimum size=1cm, align=flush center, 
 every node/.style={concept,inner sep=0pt}, concept color=violet=!30,
    level 1/.append style={level distance=3.2cm,sibling angle=120},
    level 2/.append style={level distance=0.7*3.0cm,sibling angle=60},
    level 3/.append style={level distance=0.7*2.5cm,sibling angle=50},
    level 4/.append style={level distance=0.7*2.0cm,sibling angle=60},
    ]
    \node  [left color=violet!40, middle color=red!10, right
    color=white!30,font=\bfseries,inner sep=-5mm]{Checking}
        child [concept color=violet!50] { node [minimum size=0.5*2.0cm] {State}
    child [concept color=violet!30] { node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm] {F}
        child [concept color=violet!30] {node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm]  {T}}
        }
    child [concept color=violet!30] { node  {A123}
    child [concept color=violet!30] { node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm] {12}}
    child [concept color=violet!30] { node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm] {random}}
          }
          }
          child [minimum size=0.5pt, concept color=violet!50] { node [minimum size=0.5*2.0cm] {Mix}
        child [concept color=violet!30] { node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm]  {QR}}
        child [concept color=violet!30] { node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm] {ST}}
        }
        child [minimum size=0.5pt,concept color=violet!50] { node [minimum size=0.5*2.0cm] {Next}
        child [concept color=violet!30] { node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm] {some data}
        child [concept color=violet!30] {node [text
        width=1.5cm,alias=new]  {new}}
        child[concept color=violet!30]{node[minimum size=0.5*1.5cm]  {old}
        }
        }
        child [concept color=violet!30] { node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm] {M}
         child [concept color=violet!30] {node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm]  {MS}
         child [concept color=violet!30] {node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm]  {X}}
         }
          }
        child [concept color=violet!30] { node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm] {HAS}
         child [concept color=violet!30] {node [minimum size=0.5*1.5cm]  {HAVE}}
        } 
        };
 \end{scope}  
 \node[above right=5mm of new](lnew) {next: this is next test};
 \draw[-{Stealth[bend]}] (lnew) to[out=180,in=45] (new);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Testing.} \label{mindmap}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. I have done this and it's working fine. `\node [left color=violet!5, right color=white!90, annotation, right = 1.5cm] at (n1.east) { \textbullet next: this is next text \\ };`. But can you please tell me how can I get rid of the overfull box as you have mentioned.

Comment: @user3582228 There are two options: 1. make the document wider by increasing the `\textwidth` and 1. make the mind map smaller. Which of them do you prefer? (Of course you can do a little bit of both.)

Comment: Thank you. I try to scale the nodes of mindmap by using `minimum size=0.1pt`. If I try to decrease the distance at each level it destroys the figure. Is there any way to make it smaller?